# Good error flagging | PHP

Tags: php, mysql

For everyone that was thinking of the error_reporting() function, then it isn't, what I need is whenever a MySQL query has been done, and the statement has like

```
if($result)
{
    echo "Yes, it was fine... bla bla";
}
else
{
    echo "Obviously, the echo'ing will show in a white page with the text ONLY...";
}
```

Whenever statements have been true or false, I want the error to be appeared when redirected with the header() function and echo the error reporting in a div somewhere on the page.

Basically something like this:

```
$error = '';
```

This part appears inside the div tags

```
<div><?php echo $error; ?></div>
```

So the error part will be echoed when redirected with the header()

```
if($result)
{
    $error = "Yes, it was fine... bla bla";
    header("Location: url");
}
else
{
    $error = "Something wrong happened...";
    header("Location: url");
}
```

But that just doesn't work :(

Comment: Remember that http is a request/response protocol. So your script is responding with the Location header (and basically terminates), and tells the browser to make a *new* request to your application (or wherever the url is pointing). The current value in $error is only available in the current request, not in the new request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use $_SESSION superglobal.

Sample code:

```
/* in mysql result checking */
$_SESSION["error"] = "Something wrong happened...";

/* in div tags */
if(!empty($_SESSION["error"])) {
    echo $_SESSION["error"];
    $_SESSION["error"] = "";
}
```

I also think that you need to call session_start() in the start of your script, if that wasn't done before.

Best regards,
T.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work because `error` is not declared in `url`. You're just discarding (unsetting) the `error` variable when you send the location header.

You should make your own error codes, for example:

```
0001 = ok
0002 = DB_error
...
```

and send them trough GET variables, catch'em in `url` and parse them.

```
header('Location: url?error='.urlencode($error));
```

Comment: Please wrap $error in urlencode() before gluing it to an url address. Thank you. ;-)